# Doctrine creates some undefined error

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

For some special entities (I cannot tell which ones) I get the following error when I try to do `count($Club->getUmbrellas())`, where `$Club->getUmbrellas()` is a `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`.

> Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/apache/StudCon/library/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php on line 401 Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in /var/www/apache/StudCon/library/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php on line 401

- `Club` is main.
- `ClubClub` extends `Club`
- `ClubUmbrella` extends `Club`
- `ClubUmbrella` and `ClubClub` are indirectly related over `RelationClubUmbrella`

These are the most important bits of information (please ask if u need more):

```
class Club extends \StudCon_Entity
{

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length="150")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="bigint")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;
```

---

```
class ClubClub extends Club
{

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="RelationClubUmbrella", mappedBy="club", indexBy="id")
     */
    protected $umbrellas;
```

---

```
class ClubUmbrella extends Club
{

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="RelationClubUmbrella", mappedBy="umbrella")
     */
    protected $clubs;
```

---

```
class RelationClubUmbrella
{

    const STATUS_REQUESTED = 1;
    const STATUS_CONFIRMED = 2;
    const STATUS_REJECTED = 3;


    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Club")
     * @JoinColumn(name="umbrellaid", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var Category
     */
    protected $umbrella;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Club")
     * @JoinColumn(name="clubid", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var Category
     */
    protected $club;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an outdated version of Doctrine. [Similar](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1548) [issues](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/secure/QuickSearch.jspa?searchString=ObjectHydrator) have been fixed in the meantime, you should try the [latest version](http://www.doctrine-project.org/downloads/DoctrineORM-2.1.5-full.tar.gz) (released [today](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-1-5)).